# What fill rule must be applied for Adobe Type 1 fonts and Type1 CFF fonts as used in PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts, fill

The PDF Standard (PDF 32000-1:2008) specifies two rules for filling closed paths, non-zero winding number rule ("NZW") and even-odd rule ("EO"), see p. 136-137.
Among the fonts that are allowed in PDF, my understanding is that TrueType fonts and OpenType CFF2 fonts use always NZW...

But what about Adobe Type1 fonts and Type1 CFF (compact font format) fonts (as described in section 9.6.2.1 on p. 254)? Do these also use NZW?